# How to put dashed lines between certain columns?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, beamer, arydshln

I have a table in beamer frame and I want to put dashed lines between some columns. However, I have certain constraints. First, I want to make sure that the lines are disabled after certain transition, so they should work with `visible` for example. Next, I want to be able to write a text at the top or bottom of the dashed line. I tried to use the `arydshln` package, but it doesn't seem to offer the flexibility I need.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{figure}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
%\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.2em}
\begin{tabular}{ c : c c c : c }
$e$ & $e+1$ & $e+2$ & $e+3$ & $e+4$ \\
\hline
$k_{e}$ & $k_{e+1}$ & $k_{e+2}$ & $k_{e+3}$ & $k_{e+4}$ \\

$\Delta_{e}$ & $\Delta_{e+1}$ & $\Delta_{e+2}$ & $\Delta_{e+3}$ & $\Delta_{e+4}$\\

$\sigma_{e}$ & $\sigma_{e+1}$ & $\sigma_{e+2}$ & $\sigma_{e+3}$ & $\sigma_{e+4}$ \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

More precisely, I want to achieve what's shown below. Any ideas how to do that using table or TikZ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the table is repetitive, here I would use tikz and a `\foreach` command. Something like this:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
%\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{figure}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y={(0cm,-1cm)}]
\foreach\i in {0,...,4}
{% TABLE DATA
  \ifnum \i > 0
    \def\mytext{e+\i}
  \else
    \def\mytext{e}
  \fi
  \node at (1.2*\i,0) {$\mytext$};
  \node at (1.2*\i,1) {$k_{\mytext}$};
  \node at (1.2*\i,2) {$\Delta_{\mytext}$};
  \node at (1.2*\i,3) {$\sigma_{\mytext}$};
}
% LINES
\draw[thick] (-0.6,0.5) -- (5.4,0.5);
\only<2>
{%
  \draw[thick,dashed] (0.6,-0.5) -- (0.6,3.5) node [red,below] {Text 1};
  \draw[thick,dashed] (4.2,-0.5) -- (4.2,3.5) node [red,below] {Text 2};
}
\useasboundingbox (-0.6,-0.5) rectangle (5.4,6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]
**UPDATE:** I added the `\only` command for the transition. I forgot the first time.

Comment: Thanks, works nicely! What's the purpose of `useasboundingbox`?

Comment: @pixel, the two images (the two different transitions) have different heights and these heights are used by tikz for the bounding box. As result the transition will move the table. You can see that if you delete or comment the `\useasboundingbox` command.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` and Tikz.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
\begin{figure}
\def\arraystretch{1.2}
$\begin{NiceArray}{ccccc}
e & e+1 & e+2 & e+3 & e+4 \\
\hline
k_{e} & k_{e+1} & k_{e+2} & k_{e+3} & k_{e+4} \\

\Delta_{e} & \Delta_{e+1} & \Delta_{e+2} & \Delta_{e+3} & \Delta_{e+4}\\

\sigma_{e} & \sigma_{e+1} & \sigma_{e+2} & \sigma_{e+3} & \sigma_{e+4} \\ 
\CodeAfter
  \only<2>{\tikz \draw [dashed] (1-|2) -- (last-|2) node [below] {\color{red} Text} ;}
\end{NiceArray}$
\end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]